# Can we use 'where' in a lambda function in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, lambda

I was wondering if we can use where in an anonymous function or not. I tried to do it in this way:

```
\x -> k where k = x+1
```

But this gives a parse error on 'where'.

Comment: It is not allowed, but try this instead: `\x -> let k = x+1 in k`.

Comment: So we can use let but not where. Can we use case?

Comment: Yes, `case` (and `let .. in` for that matter) are ordinary expressions, so they are allowed. For `case`, see also the `LambdaCase` extension.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `where` in certain expressions within a lambda expression, but not just inside.

```
f = \x ->
  case x of
    Nothing -> 12
    Just y -> z * 2
      where z = y + 7
```

Comment: Interesting. `case .. where` is, in my experience, quite rare to meed in actual code -- I forgot this was actually possible. :)

Comment: @chi, I personally use it a decent amount in `containers`. It's pretty useful when casing on a view. `case viewl xs of y :< ys -> ... where ...`.